# How can I print from a .NET MAUI application targeting MacOS Catalyst

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

As part of my .NET MAUI application I'd like to print an HTML document. I thought maybe having a WebView and calling window.print() would do the trick, but nothing seems to happen - am I on the right track and just missing a small thing or is this not supported (note that it doesn't throw an exception either, it just silently ignores the print request)? Source here: https://github.com/sebug/material-inout-desktop/blob/ba59581e59fe810b84eee069632c055588f1c4e6/VoucherDetailPage.xaml.cs

```
<p><button class="print">Print</button></p>
<script>
let printButton = document.querySelector('.print');
printButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    try {
        window.print();
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Erreur impression');
    }
    alert('Document imprimé');
});
</script>
```

MAUI version used:

```
dotnet workload list

Installed Workload Ids      Manifest Version      Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------
maui-maccatalyst            6.0.540/6.0.400       SDK 6.0.400        
maui-ios                    6.0.540/6.0.400       SDK 6.0.400        
maui-android                6.0.540/6.0.400       SDK 6.0.400
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Print an HTML document"?

Comment: From my application I create an HTML document, and I want to send it to a physical printer.

Comment: Convert https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8767/how-to-print-pdf-documents-in-xamarin-forms-platform to maui